# Xamarin.Forms Context Actions in ListView in android platform fire in single click

Tags: xamarin.forms

as I mention in my Question, Context Action fire in a single tap, I think normal behaviour to fire in long click

Why I refuse this behaviour as I need open new page when single clicks fired

Reference: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/#Context_Actions

Comment: Have you found a solution or the cause of it? Currently, I'm only experiencing this on Android.